How to interact in L1 only but use L2 for gas saving
I am building a dapp. I want less transaction fee but I want the users of my dapp to pay the gas fee and do the transaction in ETH. Is there any optimistic roll up, Zk rollup or and other side chain that hides whatever is going at the back end and give user an experience of using ETH only. I want no network switches in wallets etc a simple and user friendly experience for my customers. In short I want the UX to only stay with L1. Is this possible or I am asking way too much from ethereum and sidechains.

What you're asking for a user experience on Ethereum (L1) where all transactions appear to be happening on L1 but are actually leveraging a rollup or sidechain for reduced fees — is technically very challenging and currently not fully possible without some network switching or gas abstraction techniques.
However, projects like zkSync and Optimism are working towards minimizing the complexity, and gas abstraction through meta-transactions could give users the seamless L1-like experience you're looking for. But for now, a fully invisible L2 backend without network switching is still on the horizon, not fully realized.
